# where can I find some quality premium paid blog reviews for my site?

Tags: seo, blog

where can I find some premium paid blog reviews, for example, by some popular bloggers?  all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't personally condone the services, ReviewMe is a company a couple of my clients have used with pretty decent success, and even a better ROI than AdWords Campaigns.

http://www.reviewme.com/